# How would I go by checking if email is already in use?

Tags: php, html, css

I have been working on my account creation page and I am stuck onto where I should be checking if email is already in use and how to go by it. would I need to make a query statement like this

```
Select * from Customers WHERE Email = $email)
```

and check that way?

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<?php require_once("headerTH.html") ?>

<?php
$db= new PDO("sqlite:onlinestore.db");

if(ISSET($_POST['register'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $psw = sha1($_POST ['psw']);
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];

    if(! empty($email) && !empty($psw)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO Customers (UserName, Passwd, PhoneNumber, Email) VALUES(:UserName, :Passwd, :PhoneNumber, :Email)";
        $result = $db->prepare($query);

        $result->bindParam(":UserName", $username);
        $result->bindParam(":Passwd", $psw);
        $result->bindParam(":Email", $email);
        $result->bindParam(":PhoneNumber", $tel);
        // Account pass or fail
        if($result->execute()){
            echo"You have successfully created an account.{$_POST['email']}<br>";
        }else{
           ///print_r($db->errorInfo());
           require_once("create.php");
        }
    } else {
        echo "all fields are required";
        require_once("create.php");
    }
} else {
    require_once("create.php");
}
?>
<?php require_once("footerT.html")?>
```

Comment: The answer I think is YES

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Yes, although you wouldn't use SELECT * because there's no need to. You could select one column, or just SELECT COUNT(*) and recover the value. Don't get into the habit of selecting all columns when you don't need them.

Comment: And the other option is to set that column as unique in your database, then when you try to insert one that already exists, trap the error that would result from it.

Comment: Why all the `<?php` and `?>` many time with nothing between them? Not necessary

Comment: Im only using this hash as a test and see, I will not be using it in any actual instance

Comment: No, if it was just a test it would have been easier to leave the password as plain text :)

Comment: test referring to seeing how it looks and implemented on my database ( I am just learning about hashing and was curious about it) I am aware plain text is easier. thank you for your input though, i figured what needs to be done.

Comment: Be aware of case-sensitivity, which may come into play depending on what database you use, how it is configured, and how you do your comparison. [RFC 5321 §2.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-2.4) says the local-part of email addresses (left of the `@`) are case sensitive. It is up to the issuer of the email whether or not to _actually_ make it case sensitive. (Relevant phrase in §2.4 - "an argument value other than a mailbox local-part, and free form text MAY be encoded in upper case, lower case, or any mixture of upper and lower case with no impact on its meaning")

Comment: thank you Stephen P, I have made sure that any result stored in my database will default and automatically lowercase emails and usernames

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - this question is in no way related to HTML or CSS

Answer (score 1):

I think the ideal way to do this is to check if the new email exists in the database, and based on that situation. The user will be able to create the account if the new email doesn't exist in the database, otherwise you should show an alert that email already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Just required a simple if statment at the top

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Email=?");
        $stmt->execute([$email]);
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        if($user){
            //email found
            echo "Email already used";
        }else if($result->execute()){
            echo"You have successfully created an account.{$_POST['email']}<br>";
        }else{
           ///print_r($db->errorInfo());
           require_once("create.php");
        }
    } else {
        echo "all fields are required";
        require_once("create.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's me, YES, like what you said, I create a new function let say function checkUserByEmail($email) to check if the email already exists or not.

Then again you can use the same function if you need to check the user by email, let say at the time of login (if you using email for login).

By the way, DON't FORGET TO SANITIZE YOUR INPUTS ;)